# find the values of the real numbers A and B such that...

Tags: polynomials

> [image: photo of question]

i expanded and simplified the RHS to $x^4+Bx^3+4x^2+Ax^3+ABx^2+2Ax+2Bx+4$

i don’t know where to go from here.

Comment: You should *combine like terms*. For instance, instead of having two $x^3$ terms, you should have just $(A+B)x^3$

Comment: Then compare/equate coefficients. For example, there are no $x^2$ on the left. So $ 0 = AB + 4$, which is the coefficient of $x^2$ on the right.

Comment: Lastly, you can look at the zeroes of the LHS (there are no real roots) and conclude that the factors on the RHS can't have real roots. By looking at determinants, you should conclude that $A^2 < 8$, and likewise for $B^2$.

Answer (score 1):

After your expansion

$$x^4+Bx^3+2x^2+Ax^3+ABx^2+2Ax+2x^2+2Bx+4$$

Just like how you grouped the $2x^2+2x^2$, we can group like terms (same $x^i$)

$$x^4+(A+B)x^3+(AB+4)x^2+(2A+2B)x+4\equiv x^4+4$$

Now since this is true for all $x$, all the matching coefficients must be equal! (Might not be obvious)

$$x^4+(A+B)x^3+(AB+4)x^2+(2A+2B)x+4\equiv x^4+0x^3+0x^2+0x+4$$

$$A+B=0,AB+4=0,2A+2B=0$$

$$\implies A=-B,AB+4=0$$

$$\implies -B^2+4=0$$

$$A,B=2,-2$$

$$\therefore x^4+4=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$$

Comment: i understand everything up until -B^2+4=0. how do you get this? and where does the A go?

Comment: After $-B^2+4=0$ you get $B=\pm2$, and since $A=\pm B$ they're the two solutions $2,-2$.

Comment: sorry, i meant, $-B^2+4=0$ is where i don’t understand. i have no idea how you get $-B^2$ 

Comment: $A=-B,AB+4=0$ gives that

Comment: oh, just realised you solve simultaneously. sorry for my stupidity. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Another way:
$$x^4+4=x^4+4x^2+4-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$$